# How to make increasing indentations in each line before some text using recursion in java?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm new to recursive methods. I am trying to create a simple JAVA program that creates a number of steps using this symbol |_ depending on the input. each recursion is supposed to print |_ then proceed to the next line and print |_ slightly further than the previous one creating a stair-like structure.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        makeStairs(4); // invoking the method

    }

    private static void makeStairs(int steps) {

        int numstp = 0;
        if (steps > 0) {

            if (numstp != steps) {
                makeStairs(steps - 1);
                System.out.printf("|_\n");

            }
        }

    }
```

the output that I'm looking for:

```
|_
  |_
    |_
      |_
```

the output I have:

```
|_
|_   
|_
|_
```

Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can pass a String to makeStairs initially equals to “”, and in each recursive call add a space, then you have to print first this string and then |_. And you have to first print and then make the recursive call

Comment: Your `int steps` parameter is being used only to limit the depth of the recursion. In addition to that, use it to determine how far to indent.

Answer (score 0):

You are just trying to call make steps recursively, but within each recursion, you need to print whitespace, and since you are printing while you are exiting the recursion, you may want to do some math to determine the number of blanks to print.
Looks like a homework problem so wont give the full solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this easily by printing some blank spaces    immediately before printing the step itself `|_`

The number of spaces    will be equal to the value `steps`

*Keep in mind that each space is actually 2 spaces*

So, you can use a for loop as follows

```
for (int i = 1; i < steps; i++){
    System.out.print("  ");
}
```

Place this between `makeStairs(steps - 1);` and your `printf` statement

**Output**

```
|_
  |_
    |_
      |_
```